# apply a border-left to the first li element auto-generated by jQuery bxSlider plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bxslider

I am looking for a way to apply a border-left on the first `li` *only* that is generated by the jQuery bxSlider plugin which is 'active', i.e. has a class of `pager`. This is the output generated by the bxSlider plugin:

```
<div class="bx-window" style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; width:969px;">
    <ul id="carousel_items" style="width: 999999px; position: relative; left: -323px;">
        <li style="width: 304px; float: left; list-style: none outside none; opacity: 1;">CONTENT IN HERE</li>
        <li class="pager" style="width: 304px; float: left; list-style: none outside none; opacity: 1;">CONTENT IN HERE</li>
        <!-- other LIs in here -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

I do not want to apply a 1px border-left on all elements as this would lead to a 2px border on joining elements as I also have a border-right of 1px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#carousel_items.li:first-child { border-left:1px solid red; }
```

Comment: This does not appear to work and I believe the reason is likely to be because the markup is generated by the jQuery bxSlider plugin. I assumed this would have to be modified with jQuery rather than CSS - am I right?

Comment: No, this is straight CSS.  Are you inserting this CSS AFTER the bxSlider CSS declarations?  Which browser are you testing in?